# Geoserver Openlayer maps aren't showing

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver

**Update**
When i use the default layer, the layer being shown in map. but im trying custom layer. Thats wony working. Is there anything to take care while creating postgis connection, namespace while creating workspace and all?

```
var points = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8086/geoserver/test/wms',
        params: {
        'LAYERS': 'test:points_data',                            
        'VERSION': '1.1.0'     
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
    });
```

In geoserver i can access the layer.

[Open layer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqxRW.png)

I'm using
Tomcat 9.0_Tomcat9.1
OpenLayers-2.13.1
geoext2-2.1.0

**Edit:**

i updated openlayer version

```
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
```

But still have same error

The response is a blank image
[console inspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOdSW.png)

Comment: The code you have shown is for OpenLayers 3 or later.  It won't if you are using OpenLayers 2.13.1

Comment: that didnt worked, i updated openlayer version

Comment: it returns blank img

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your server URL. try this:

```
var points = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8086/geoserver/wms',
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'test:points_data',                                 
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
});
```

As you can see in this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-image.html) you dont need to put workspace name in url. so `http://localhost:8086/geoserver/wms` is fine.